# symantec endpoint protection service stuck at stopping

Tags: windows-server-2003, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection

I am trying to uninstall Symantec Endpoint Protection, but I can't, the services stuck at stopping.  Symantec Endpoint Protection is installed on Windows 2003 R2 server.  Any suggestions on how to do it without rebooting the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Getting out alive without a reboot is pretty unlikely. Did you use Symantec's removal tool? https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?docid=20080710133834EN&product=home&pvid=f-home&version=1&lg=english&ct=us

Comment: It won't install on Server OS.  And I would still need to reboot it.  I also have backup exec that I want to keep on that machine.

Comment: Anybody managed to find cause of this? It is still happening in our company and the only known solution is restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `End Process`/`End Process Tree` from `Task Manager`.  (Or try to terminate a process it's dependent on, if any - sometimes this will crash the process for you.)

(There's also a CLI command, `taskkill /f`, if you're a CLI junky.)

If that doesn't work, you have a "zombie process" which is hung waiting on a kernel resource.  To kill a zombie process, you have to stop the kernel, which means rebooting.